# No action being perform after clicking the export button in PHP Export with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add features in my system as to exporting the generated table in excel. Upon clicking the export button, This shall export the file based on the query condition on the codes below. However, It does not happen as expected. I think I have an error in the onclick function or as to the code and data submission. The stated station id is the id of my optionbox

export button

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="export_ctlist" name="export_ctlist"><i class="fas fa-download"></i><span> </span>  Export to Excel</button>
    
<script>
$("#export_ctlist").click(function () {
  var ct_station = $("#station_id").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "export.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      ct_station: ct_station,
      action: "export_ch",
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (dataResultxu2) {
      $("#alerts").html(dataResultxu2);
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

export.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbcon.php';
$output = '';
if ($_POST['action'] == "export_ch") {
    $ct_station = $_POST['ct_station'];
    $x = "0";
    $x++;

    $ct_list = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ct LEFT JOIN station on ct.station_id=station.station_id where station.station_id= '$ct_station'") or die(mysqli_error());

    $output .= '
                <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="1">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="3">#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Address</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Birthday</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Age</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Gender</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Level of Education</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Course</th>
                                <th class="text-center">School</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Previous work affected by COVID-19</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Training Date</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Deployment Date</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Previous Employer</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>';

    $optional_fields = ["ct_SName"];
    $optional_field1 = ["cluster_id"];
    while ($ct_row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($ct_list)) {
        foreach ($ct_row_list as $name => &$value) {
            if (in_array($name, $optional_fields)) {
                continue;
            } elseif (empty($value)) {
                $value = " ";
            }
        }
        $station = $ct_row_list['station_name'];
        $ct_FName = $ct_row_list['ct_FName'];
        $ct_MName = $ct_row_list['ct_MName'];
        $ct_LName = $ct_row_list['ct_LName'];
        $ct_SName = $ct_row_list['ct_SName'];
        $ct_address = $ct_row_list['ct_address'];
        $ct_birthday = $ct_row_list['ct_birthday'];
        $ct_age = $ct_row_list['ct_age'];
        $ct_gender = $ct_row_list['ct_gender'];
        $ct_level_educ = $ct_row_list['ct_level_educ'];
        $ct_course = $ct_row_list['ct_course'];
        $ct_school = $ct_row_list['ct_school'];
        $ct_prev_covid = $ct_row_list['ct_prev_covid'];
        $ct_training_date = $ct_row_list['ct_training_date'];
        $ct_deployment_date = $ct_row_list['ct_deployment_date'];
        $ct_prev_emp = $ct_row_list['ct_prev_emp'];

        $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ' . $x++ . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_FName . ' ' . $ct_MName . ' ' . $ct_LName . ' ' . $ct_SName . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_address . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_birthday . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_age . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_gender . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_level_educ . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_course . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_school . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_prev_covid . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_training_date . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_deployment_date . '
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ' . $ct_prev_emp . '
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    header('Content-Type: application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ct_list.xls');
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: Is it true that you have two files (one is HTML and one is PHP) ?

Comment: Yes sir. Its true

Comment: It feels like you expect your HTML to be magically converted to XLS just by adding a header... Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913353/convert-html-code-into-xls-xlsx) for a start.

Comment: No there are 2 files here., i,ve put a comment in php file as my redirection fornthe code.,

Comment: My point is your are echoing some HTML... And the only thing referring to some XLS is the header. That won't work.

Comment: Have a look at [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

change this code :

```
$('#export_ctlist').click(function(){
```

TO :

```
<button id="export_ctlist">click me</button>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('export_ctlist');
button.onclick = function() {
//You code here
alert('success');
}
</script>
```

Its work tested ;-)
if still not you sould change you jquery.js
TO

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure jQuery is included in your project.
Then try this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#export_ctlist").on('click', function () {
    var ct_station = $("#station_id").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "export.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        ct_station: ct_station,
        action: "export_ch",
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function (dataResultxu2) {
        $("#alerts").html(dataResultxu2);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

If still not works, Check your browser console log to fix previous errors